# UITableViewCell backgroundView image is not downloading & showing right images

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a customized UITableViewCell with some attributes. The goal is to update each cell with a different background image (downloaded from the web asynchronously). I have ten cells to show, but the problem is that the bottom 5 cells always show the first five images downloaded (thats downloaded for the top 5 cells).

To avoid downloading the images again when a cell reloads when user scrolls, I use a table view cell attribute called isImageLoaded. See the snippet below. Tried multiple solutions to fix this without avail. I do show text attributes for these cells as well (not fetched through HTTP requests) and they show correct values for all the 10 cells scrolling up and down.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:ImageTableCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! ImageTableCell

    cell.tag = indexPath.section

    // cell.imageLoaded is initialized as false in the custom cell settings
    if !(cell.imageLoaded) {
        var photourl:String = "http://someurl/image" + String(indexPath.section)
            downloadImage(cell, url: NSURL(string: photourl)!)
        }
    }

func downloadImage(cell:HomeSummaryTableCell, url:NSURL){
        cell.activityindicator.startAnimating()
        println("Started downloading \"\(url.lastPathComponent!.stringByDeletingPathExtension)\".")
        getDataFromUrl(url) { data in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                println("Finished downloading \"\(url.lastPathComponent!.stringByDeletingPathExtension)\".")
                var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(data: data!))
                imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
                imageView.clipsToBounds = true
                cell.backgroundView = imageView
                cell.activityindicator.stopAnimating()
                cell.imageLoaded = true
            }
        }
}

func getDataFromUrl(urL:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?) -> Void)) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urL) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: data)
        }.resume()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because dequed cell retains the values of set properties, so you need to reset your imageLoaded parameter when preparing for reuse.
In your custom cell, override `prepareForReuse` and set `imageLoaded` to `false`.

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        imageLoaded = false
    }
```

Comment: Works (thanks), but with an overhead of downloading the image again and updating the cell. That means I should be using the imageLoaded logic properly to avoid re-download. Will work and update how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, for that you should use image caching. You can build your own or search cocoapods ;)